# How to iterate through all UIButtons on screen in Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to do a loop to iterate through all UIButtons found on the view in order to change the position of each button. (See code below)

```
        for case let button as UIButton in self.view.subviews {
             rect = button.frame
             rect.origin.x = rect.origin.x + 20
             rect.origin.y = rect.origin.y + 20
             button.frame = rect
        }
```

However, when I debugged the code I found that the loop is not finding any buttons, and thus the positions remained the same. I have 9 buttons in a View found in the View Controller.

Anyone knows what's wrong with this loop?

Comment: Are your buttons direct subviews of `self.view` or are they further down in the view hierarchy?

Comment: @rmaddy the hierarchy is like this View Controller -> View -> Buttons

Answer (score 4):

Your code works fine for me. The implication is that your buttons are *not* subviews of `self.view`, but subviews of some view further down the hierarchy. You will have to write a recursive version of your loop.

For example:

```
func lookForButton(_ v: UIView) {
    let subs = v.subviews
    if subs.count == 0 {return}
    for vv in subs {
        if vv is UIButton {
            print(vv) // just testing: do your real stuff here
        }
        lookForButton(vv)
    }
}
lookForButton(self.view)
```

Comment: I don't believe you want that 2nd `return` statement in this code. That will skip any other buttons at the current level.

Comment: @rmaddy It might be otiose, but I think it is fair to assume that a UIButton has, itself, no subviews worth looking for. In particular, it surely won't have another button as its subview. So why waste the cycles?

Comment: But `subs` may have more than one button. That `return` will cause only the first button to be handled.

Comment: @rmaddy arrggh.

Comment: To get the efficiency you want, put the `lookForButton(vv)` in an `else` from the `if vv is UIButton`.

Comment: @matt I managed to resolve the issue by dragging the UIView on ViewController.swift and update the code to 'for case let button as UIButton in self.topView.subviews'. Maybe it's sounds silly but I'm new to swift :) Your answer was still useful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working. This:

```
var view = UIView()
view.addSubview(UIView())
view.addSubview(UIButton())

for case let button as UIButton in view.subviews {
    print(button)
}
```

prints:

```
<UIButton: 0x7fcc9bd07320; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000002dca0>>
```

Conclusion: self.view.subviews does not contain any `UIButtons`.

Comment: This is not a valid test. Don't create a `UIView` array. Create a `UIView` then add the other views as subviews.

Comment: UIView.subviews _is_ an array of UIViews. Updated answer anyway to be more precise. Maybe add a log of self.view.subviews.